# How to simulate virtual scrolling of jqGrid programatically in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, scroll, simulation

I am using jqGrid with "scroll: true" option. It works fine, but I have to scroll programatically in one situation.

Is it possible to simulate virtual scrolling in jqGrid programatically? I would like to simulate from code situation when user is on the end of some page, and than next scroll will load next page into grid. Is it possible?

I tried with:

```
$("#jqTable").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: next_page }]);
```

but it does not work. I don't see rows of next page.

Comment: Whatever is next_page, 2 or 3, my grid send page=1 to LoadData method!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved virtual scrolling with:

$("#jqTable").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(2400);

Still, I cannot get ids immediatelly after this line of code, but this is next question.

Comment: I will get IDs if I apply some timeout on code after this line.

Comment: I used 
$("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(2400);
as my table name is list. It didn't work. But Previously it worked. Should I use a different selector?